# How to extract directory path from file path?

Tags: bash

In Bash, if `VAR="/home/me/mydir/file.c"`, how do I get `"/home/me/mydir"`?

Comment: A much more sophisticated and complex real directory path resolution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789204/bash-how-to-get-real-path-of-a-symlink/55254754#55254754

Answer (score 946, accepted):

`dirname` and `basename` are the tools you're looking for for extracting path components:

```
$ VAR='/home/pax/file.c'
$ DIR="$(dirname "${VAR}")" ; FILE="$(basename "${VAR}")"
$ echo "[${DIR}] [${FILE}]"
[/home/pax] [file.c]
```

They're not internal `bash` commands but they are part of the POSIX standard -  see [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) and [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html). Hence, they're probably available on, or can be obtained for, most platforms that are capable of running `bash`.

Comment: Why the use of brackets around the variable names, and not "$VAR" for example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-around-shell-variables answers the above question.

Comment: @user658182 In this particular example, it is done out of habit, not necessity.

Comment: The `export` is unnecessary and the [`echo`s are useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: @tripleee: the `export` is a habit of mine, simply to ensure the variable is passed to sub-shells. The `echo` statements are to show how you could get the output into a variable, but I should probably have gone the whole hog on that (which I now have). Though neither of those really affect the "meat" of the answer, I'll adjust. I'm always appreciative of constructive criticism on improving my answers.

Answer (score 142):

```
$ export VAR=/home/me/mydir/file.c
$ export DIR=${VAR%/*}
$ echo "${DIR}"
/home/me/mydir

$ echo "${VAR##*/}"
file.c
```

To avoid dependency with `basename` and `dirname`

Comment: Since both are part of POSIX a dependency should not be a problem.

Comment: orkoden , you're right. The aim of my answer is to show there is no obligation to execute two additional process. bash is self sufficient for the use case.

Comment: I am using Emmanuel's method because I wish to pass either a file or a folder name, and then compute the folder path. Using this regex does the right thing, whereas the dirname function returned the parent folder when I input a folder.

Comment: However, if there's no path info in $VAR, ${VAR%/*}/test produces an unexpected value equal to $VAR/test whereas $(dirname $VAR) will produce the more predictable and appropriate value of ./test. This is a big deal because the former will attempt to treat the filename as a directory while the latter will be OK.

Comment: The `export` is unnecessary here. The purpose of `export` is to make the variable visible in the environment of the shell's subprocesses, but you are not calling any subprocesses which use the environment to access this information.

Comment: This should arguably be the accepted answer. `dirname` and `basename` have their place, but if the path is already in a shell variable, using the shell's built-in facilities is more efficient and elegant than calling an external process.

Comment: Another benefit of this is it is much MUCH faster than `dirname` I'm running it in a loop with 1000 items and dirname takes seconds whereas this is nearly instantaneous

Answer (score 43):

On a related note, if you only have the filename or relative path, `dirname` on its own won't help. For me, the answer ended up being `readlink`.

```
fname='txtfile'    
echo $(dirname "$fname")                # output: .
echo $(readlink -f "$fname")            # output: /home/me/work/txtfile
```

You can then combine the two to get just the directory.

```
echo $(dirname $(readlink -f "$fname")) # output: /home/me/work
```

Comment: if more than one path component not existed, you should use `readlink -m "$fname"` to canonicalize given name recursively

Answer (score 7):

If you care target files to be symbolic link, firstly you can check it and get the original file. The if clause below may help you.

```
if [ -h $file ]
then
 base=$(dirname $(readlink $file))
else
 base=$(dirname $file)
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

```
HERE=$(cd $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE) && pwd)
```

where you get the full path with **new_path**=`$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})`. You change current directory with `cd` **new_path** and then run `pwd` to get the full path to the current directory.

Comment: Brilliant, the most polymorphic option!

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question actually. [The quoting is broken.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 4):

I was playing with this and came up with an alternative.

```
$ VAR=/home/me/mydir/file.c

$ DIR=`echo $VAR |xargs dirname`

$ echo $DIR
/home/me/mydir
```

The part I liked is it was easy to extend backup the tree:

```
$ DIR=`echo $VAR |xargs dirname |xargs dirname |xargs dirname`

$ echo $DIR
/home
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this using approach for [How to find the last field using 'cut'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727211/2402577):

**Explanation**

- `rev` reverses `/home/user/mydir/file_name.c` to be `c.eman_elif/ridym/resu/emoh/`
- `cut` uses `/` as the delimiter, and chooses the second field, which is `ridym/resu/emoh/`, which deletes string up to the first occurrence of `/`
- lastly, we reverse it again to get `/home/user/mydir`

```sh
$ VAR="/home/user/mydir/file_name.c"
$ echo $VAR | rev | cut -d"/" -f2- | rev
/home/user/mydir
```

Comment: Replacing '/' (not valid within a file name) with space (valid within a file name) is not recommended.  If you must use such a solution, better to just remove everything up until, and including, the last '/' character.

Comment: @MartynDavis Please see my updated answer based on your suggestion

Comment: This is not what the OP requested.

Comment: @m42 updated my answer according to OP requested. Please see its updated version.

Comment: @alper; yeah now that's what the OP requested. :)

Comment: @m42 Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I used for recursive trimming. Replace $1 with the directory you want, of course.

```
BASEDIR=$1
IFS=$'\n'
cd "$BASEDIR"
 for f in $(find . -type f -name ' *')
 do 
    DIR=$(dirname "$f")
    DIR=${DIR:1}
    cd "$BASEDIR$DIR"
    rename 's/^ *//' *
 done
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop over the output of `find` is an antipattern and a source of many bugs. This construct is inherently limited, and will fail if `find` produces results which contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters, let alone then newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I like my paths absolute, and I need it from the (first) bash parameter (not a variable, not `$pdf`, not script location):

i.e. to reliably create a subfolder next to my chosen file ($1):

```
rp="$(realpath $(dirname $1)/pfd_extract)"
mkdir -p "$rp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
VAR='/home/pax/file.c'
DIR="$(echo $VAR | sed 's|\(.*\)\/.*|\1|g')"
FILE="$(echo $VAR | sed 's|.*\/\(.*\)|\1|g')"
echo "[${DIR}] [${FILE}]"
[/home/pax] [file.c]
```