# Reading data from properties file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, properties-file

I am writing a shell script which reads data from a properties file and stores in into a local variable in shell script. The problem is when i am trying to read multiple properties from the file and form a string its getting over written

```
#!/bin/bash
. /opt/oracle/scripts/user.properties

echo $username
echo $password
echo $service_name

conn=$username$password$service_name
echo $conn
```

the values of username=xxxx password=yyyy and service_name=zzzz i expect the output to be

```
xxxxyyyyzzzz
```

but instead of that i am getting the output as

```
zzzz
```

please tell me where am i doing the mistake ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm certain that the file `/opt/oracle/scripts/user.properties` contains [CR+LF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) line endings.  (Running the `file` command for the properties file would say `... with CRLF line terminators`).  Changing those to `LF` using `dos2unix` or any other utility should make it work.

Moreover, instead of saying:

```
conn=$username$password$service_name
```

you could say:

```
conn="${username}${password}${service_name}"
```

Comment: thanks devnull that worked perfectly.I never imagined that line endings would cause an issue.

Comment: @devnull can you tell when we have to use the "{}" curly brackets and when not.

Comment: @Avenger for reference have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables-using-bash, and more broadly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces