# Appending text to the end of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, string-concatenation

The following works, but I don't want the space that it returns:

```
read input
file= "$input"
file= "$file ins.b" # how to get rid of the space here?
echo "$file"
```

This outputs 'file ins.b'
I don't want the space between file and ins.b

If I don't leave that space in the code it returns only '.b'. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Review [How can I concatenate string variables in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash). It isn't quite a duplicate because it wants the space that you don't want, but some of the answers cover the cases you need covered.  (For example, you could use `file="$file""ins.b"` or `file="$file"ins.b`; these are covered alternatives, as well as the simple `file="${file}ins.b"`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append like:

```
file="${file}ins.b"
```

If you don't use braces then it treats `fileins` as a variable and expands it. Since, it's probably not set it just prints `.b`.

Related: [When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-why-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to expand the old value at all; bash has a `+=` operator:

```
file+="ins.b"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can also reference variables like `${file}`. So this should work for you:

```
file="${file}ins.b"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file="${file}ins.b"
```

or

```
file=$file"ins.b"
```