# shell script variables - how to finalize substituition

Tags: shell

I define two variables in a shell script

```
RELEASE_TYPE="release"
CERT_TYPE="Prod"
```

and then I want to use it in something like this:

```
-l somepath/$RELEASE_TYPE/AndroidTZ1_4/tz-$CERT_TYPE
/something_release_Prod_non_relocatable.lib
```

As you can see, I use $RELEASE_TYPE and $CERT_TYPE when there's a trailing forward slash, but how can I use these vars also on the last bit, i.e. `/something_$RELEASE_TYPE_$CERT_TYPE_non_relocatable.lib`? If I do that, the vars are not evaluated at all, i.e. I end up with `something_` and none of the rest.
Also tried with `+` and other chars, nothing gets me what I expected.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: Why do we need curly braces in variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-why-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the variable names with curly braces.

```
/something_${RELEASE_TYPE}_${CERT_TYPE}_non_relocatable.lib
```