# No such file for directory error

Tags: shell

i try to get line count in the every log files as bellow code but bellow code gave to me error as **No such file or directory** in `line_count=$(wc -l < "{$entry}")`
line i can't understand why that gave error because in the above line i print file name also

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/var/log"

declare -i line_count

for entry in $FILE/* ; do
   echo "{$entry}" # auth.log
    line_count=$(wc -l < "{$entry}") # No such file or directory

    echo "{$line_count}"
done
```

Comment: That this prints `{auth.log}` instead of `auth.log` should have been a hint. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake using shell variables.

Try replacing `{$variable}` with `${variable}`

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/var/log"

declare -i line_count

for entry in $FILE/* ; do
   echo "${entry}" # auth.log
   line_count=$(wc -l < "${entry}") # change to this

   echo "${line_count}"
done
```

[more about shell variables and braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)

Answer (score -1):

It's the curly braces around `$entry`. Remove them:

```
line_count=$(wc -l < "$entry")
```

Comment: Your suggestion would break the script funtionality if there were files with the spaces for some reason in that dir

Comment: The curly braces (if put correctly as in `${entry}`) are correct, a good habit to get into, and actually necessary if you want to get something like `wc -l "${foo}_${bar}"`. Not my downvote though. @JanLutenko: Actually, no -- it's the quotation marks that ensure correct behaviour here, not the braces.

Comment: @DevSolar oh, yes you're right. I have a habit of always using "${}" and mixed those two just because I'm sure I don't have to worry about variable expansion any more.