# The copy command doesn't work when appending date

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script:

```
date=$( date +%F ) 
cp $1 $1_$date
```

When written this way and provided a single argument, it works fine. But if I write:

```
cp $1 $date_$1
```

I get an error message:

> cp: ‘1.sh’ and ‘1.sh’ are the same file

Could someone explain to me, please, why it happens and how it can be solved. Thanks!

Comment: cp $1 $date"_$1" works. this way bash knows when one variable name ends and the other starts

Comment: Use ${date} which tells where variable ends

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate (though I'm sure we could  find one) but the explanation is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `_` is a perfectly valid character in a variable name.

Rewrite like this:

```
cp $1 ${date}_$1
```

What's happening is the value of `$date_` (notice the trailing `_`), is probably empty. So your command becomes really `cp $1 $1`. By using the braces, we clarify that the name of the variable is "date" and not "date_".

You should also quote variables used is filenames, in case they contain spaces:

```
cp "$1" "${date}_$1"
```

Comment: No braces are necessary in the first, because `1_` is not a valid parameter name.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I should have tested that first :-/ Dropped that point.