# Linux environmental variable defined but not reflecting value

Tags: linux, variables, environment

Please help me understand and possibly explain this.
Suppose I have 2 env variables:

```
$REL --> foo
$MEL --> bar
```

Now if I `echo $REL$MEL` it works.

If I `echo test$REL`, it works.(testfoo)

But why Linux is not able to identify the variable when used like this:   `$RELtest`?

I understand this looks like the stupidest question but is there a way to tell the system to look for the matching part of the string in env variables already set and replace that part?

I also understand that when doing `test$REL`, it is `$` that works as an identifier.
If this is not possible then how to explain the limitation?
Any usage example in docs where this is shown prohibited will help me a lot.

Comment: You need braces to indicate which parts of the text are the variable name whenit's not all of them. `echo "${REL}test"`

Answer (score 3):

With `$RELtest`, the shell interprets it as the value of the variable `RELtest` - it is not able to figure out that you meant `REL` followed by a literal `test` since there is no delimiter. You need to be more explicit - use `{}` to quote the variable:

```
$ echo ${REL}test
footest
```

See also [When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)