# Difference between ${my_variable} and $my_variable in a Jenkins project

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Is there a difference when using variables in a Jenkins project between this:

`node index.js ${arg}`

and this:

`node index.js $arg`

Where arg is a parameter for the project.

**Update:**
Interesting to note that it's not Jenkins-specific.

I think this question should remain as others may assume it's something to do with Jenkins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: When do we need curly braces in variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a standard shell syntax.

It's easier to manipulate variables / concatenate the contents of variables into other variable names. e.g.

```
${foo}bar
```

You can also perform additional string manipulation with the `{}`:

```
STRING="This is a string"
echo ${STRING// /_}
```

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

I also find variables with `{}` to read better but that's a personal preference.

Generic answer here: [When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables)

Answer (score 3):

In the context of your Jenkins project, it is not needed, except as a matter of style.

The braces are useful in those cases where the shell may not be able to determine the end of a variable name.  For instance, if your variable is named `this`, then you would need the braces if your command was

```
echo "${this}isatest"
```

Also, you need them when you want to take advantage of Bash's [Shell Parameter Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).