# Creating multiple files with the names saved in text

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

Say, I have a list.txt contained the names:

```
Book Summary to Complete
Jargon to Collect
Open Problem to Solve
Wordlist to Filter
...
etc
```

1. How can I create files with its names saved in list.txt?
2. For more usage, say the list.txt is updated period, how can I create the rest of files as soon as list.txt updated?

Thanks

Comment: And your code? Or we should write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create files with its names saved in list.txt?

You can either loop through the output of `cat`

```
 cat "list.txt" | while read LINE; do
     touch "./${LINE}"
 done
```

or make `read` read from file descriptor other than standard input

```
 while read -u 4 LINE; do
     touch "./${LINE}"
 done 4<list.txt
```

There might be lots of solutions though.

Just remember to enclose your variable references in double quotes and [curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables-using-bash) as long as the value of your variable may contain spaces.

> For more usage, say the list.txt is updated period, how can I create the rest of files as soon as list.txt updated?

Basically this can be achieved by something monstrous like checking for changes in file in an infinite loop, but I doubt this is what you want.

Can you be more descriptive?
How and where do you want to use your `list.txt` file?