# Why Pycharm gives warning on "simple variable usage" in .sh bash script?

Tags: bash, pycharm

In Pycharm when we use variable e.g. `$privateKey`, we get the warning **Simple variable usage** as below snapshot and recommend us to turn to the syntax `${privateKey}`

My question is why we get such warning? What is the risk to use simple variable like that?

[image]

When clicking `more`

[image]

Comment: It is perfectly valid and not-problematic in your use case, what does clicking the `more` link show?

Comment: It shows ${X} syntax as my added 2nd snapshot @heemayl

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see the reason to have a warning like this. If we know what we are doing, we can perfectly use `$privateKey` for a bash variable...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Whymarrh. One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/248616) is as below.

> since "$foobar" would instead expand foobar

My answer is to separate/distinguish `$myVar` and `notInVar` in string `"$myVarnotInVar"`

In other words

```
myVar=122

echo "$myVarnotInVar" # will print empty string "" since undefined variable $myVarnotInVar

echo "${myVar}notInVar" # will print 122notInVar
```

Comment: what? please explain more

Comment: @AlexanderMills Updated with verbose expained