# ./configure: No such file or directory when getting tar.gz file

Tags: linux, shell, tar, atom-editor

I'm creating a mac setup shell script and testing out installing Atom. They give instructions on how to [Install the source](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/macos.md), but installing source tends to take a lot longer than installing binaries.

When I run the `sh` script, It gets and installs the binaries,

> ./configure: No such file or directory

From here:

```
...
x atom-1.12.7/vendor/jasmine-jquery.js
x atom-1.12.7/vendor/jasmine.js
ln: /usr/local/bin/atom: File exists
/Users/danniu/Desktop/Configs/Bash Setup/mac_setup_script/install_atom.sh: line 10: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Password: _____
```

I've tried [following these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324261/configure-no-such-file-or-directory-even-after-installing-build-essentials), and added `./configure --prefix=~/user/local/bin/atom` to configure, but it gives the same issue.

**Script**:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/testing123
cd ~/Desktop/testing123
ATOM_VER=1.12.7
echo "Hello $USER. Installing Atom v$ATOM_VER"
wget https://github.com/atom/atom/archive/v$ATOM_VER.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v$ATOM_VER.tar.gz
ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom
./configure
make
sudo make install
apm install atom-beautify
apm install docblockr
apm install pigments
```

Comment: If you remove the `/usr/local/bin/atom` and run as su? What happens?

Comment: So when you extract teh tar.gz file, does it scatter files all over your desktop? or is there a directory there, perhaps named atom-version or something?   Normally a tarball will have a top level directory, and inside of that is where everything will be - including the configure script

Comment: @ivanivan no. It's all contained within `~/Desktop/testing123`

Comment: Then when you extract it, you need to cd to ./testing123 - then run the ./configure

Comment: It looks like atom doesn't have `configure` script. In the `git` you pasted, it says `script/build`. Use this script instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing step in your script:

```
cd atom-${ATOM_VER}
```

right after `tar` and before `configure`.

**EDIT:**
This is based on the assumption that a `configure` script exists!

Comment: this gives the same error. Why are you using `{ }` btw with variables?

Comment: Did you check if `configure` really exists? re- '{VAR}`: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables-using-bash)

Comment: Which folder would `configure` exist in?

Comment: under atom-1.12.7. If this is not the case I'd suggest to check the atom documentation