# Bash: variable not getting expanded properly

Tags: bash, variables

I am trying to use variable in renaming a file. However, I when insert the variable to the beginning of the filename, things does not work as expected.

Here's the case, I have a file name test:

```
$ ls
test
```

and a variable
`i=1`

When adding the variable to the end or middle of filename, it works:

```
$ mv test test_$i
$ ls
test_1
```

When adding the variable to the beginning of filename, it doesn't work:

```
$mv test_1 test  
$mv test $i_test
mv: missing destination file operand after 'test'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

And even worse, when there is extension in my filename, the file will be removed.

```
$ touch test.try
$ ls
test.try
$ mv test.try $i_test.try
$ ls
 (nothing!)
```

Can anyone explain this to me? Is it a bug or something I don't know?

Comment: Always quote your variables. Try `mv test "$i"_test`

Comment: Note that the missing file has been renamed to `.try` — it is still there (use `ls -a` to see it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `{}` around the variable name to disambiguate it from the rest of the literal (remember, `_` is a valid character in an identifier):

```
mv test.try ${i}_test.try
```

or, use double quotes, which gives you protection against word splitting and globbing:

```
mv test.try "${i}"_test.try
```

In your code:

```
$i_test     => shell treats "i_test" as the variable name
$i_test.try => shell treats "i_test" as the variable name ('.' is not a valid character in an identifier)

mv test.try $i_test.try => test.try got moved to .try as "$i_test" expanded to nothing.  That is why ls didn't find that file.  Use 'ls -a' to see it.
```

---

See this related post: [When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables-using-bash)