# Inserting Variable into sh Script Command

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh -f

set proj_dir="OutputDir"
for projname in lib proj1 proj2
do
    mv ./scripts/$projname_BYTECODE ./$proj_dir/scripts/$projname
done
```

A very simple example of what is not working well for me.  $projname_BYTECODE is being interpreted as a variable name but _BYTECODE is actually part of the folder name.  Suggestions?

Comment: ${projname}_BYTECODE?

Comment: You know, I "tried" that, but the syntax highlighting on gedit said it was still one variable so I did not actually try it.  That does seem to have worked, though.  You should answer the question.

Comment: As an aside; you've got some quoting bugs still present -- http://shellcheck.net/ will catch them.

Comment: `set` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I put that in there accidentally when making this post.  My script did not have that but copying&pasting was not working from my Linux VM at the time.  So when I was typing it up, I mixed in some Tcl/Tk that I am unfortunately learning recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `${X}` instead of `$X`, so in your example `${projname}_BYTECODE` should do the trick. Have a look at this question for more information: [When do we need curly braces in variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables-using-bash)