# shell script to move 2 files from one dir to another and rename it

Tags: bash, shell

I want to move 2 files from current directory to archive directory and rename the files while doing it with prefixing the date and changing the file extension. the script below it does work if i remove the move directory part of it. please see script and error message blow. the permission on the archive directory is 777 so is the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
  cdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  destdir=${/home/dcaceres/load/archive}
   for file in allcustomer.csv loadcustomer.csv; do
    mv "$file" "$destdir/$cdate"_"$file"".ARCHIVE"
  done 

    the error.
    ./archive_customer_load.sh: line 3: /home/dcaceres/load/archive: Is a directory

mv: cannot move 'allcustomer.csv' to '/2017-12-12_allcustomer.csv.ARCHIVE': Permission denied

mv: cannot move 'loadcustomer.csv' to '/2017-12-12_loadcustomer.csv.ARCHIVE': Permission denied
```

Comment: Try changing `destdir=${/home/dcaceres/load/archive}` to `destdir="/home/dcaceres/load/archive"`

Comment: thanks that worked. appreciated

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can really help in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line below will do the work:

```
destdir=${/home/dcaceres/load/archive}
```

to:

```
destdir="/home/dcaceres/load/archive"
```

**Explanation:**

Curly brackets are needed when using variables, that too is not always necessary. It is useful in many cases, for example, concatenating a string to value of a variable, when using an array or when using parameter expansion.

Here in your case, we just need to assign the variable `destdir` with a `string`, so we can directly do it with quotes.

For more information: [When do we need curly braces around shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-around-shell-variables)