# gitlab-ci SSH key invalid format

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like run deploy script with gitlab-ci, but step ssh-add `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` return an error :

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
```

You can see my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
deploy:
  image: node:9.11.1-alpine
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk add --update openssh )'

    # Add bash
    - apk add --update bash

    # Add git
    - apk add --update git

    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -

    # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
    # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
    # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
    # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    # In order to properly check the server's host key, assuming you created the
    # SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS variable previously, uncomment the following two lines
    # instead.
    # - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    # - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
  script:
    - npm i -g pm2
    - pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production
  # only:
  # - master
```

On my project setting, i've been add SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable, with the id_rsa from my production server `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: it is the SSH public key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub while the private key is contained in ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: @pfctgeorge I dumbly copied the wrong file as well :P You should move your comment into an answer. I will come back and upvote it.

Answer (score 99):

In my case, it was because I had made my **SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable protected**. When I disabled the Protected state, it worked without any error.

[image]

Comment: Also make sure to set the variable as type `VARIABLE`, not `FILE`

Comment: It solved it for me even though my target branch was protected. Any idea why?

Comment: this did not work for me, also its a workaround and should be considered as a bug (which they maybe have solved by now?)

Comment: Or you could make the branch protected. In that case the variable can remain protected as well!

Answer (score 70):

In my case I had to put a new line at the end of the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable

Comment: could yo clarify how to added a new line? I tried with \n without any success

Comment: @FelixOuttaSpace just press enter at the end

Comment: I had the variable protected and as file, and it was a requirement. Adding a space solved my issue too.

Answer (score 35):

I made a stupid mistake and added the key without `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` clauses.

Summing up, you should add:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<< the key itself goes here >>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Also, ensure the newline after the closing is present.

Answer (score 17):

for all people reaching this post not finding a solution yet.

Try to make the branch protected, because its a must for protected variables.

> Protected: Only exposed to protected branches or protected tags.

[Add a CI/CD variable to a project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project)

Answer (score 9):

It works with variable expansion (curly brackets in double string quotation):

```
  - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | ssh-add -
```

While keeping the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable protected!

This approach is simply a [less ambiguous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/5316326) for printing variables; in this case it prevents trimming of the last line break.

Comment: Do you have an idea about what the "-" means after ssh-add ?

Comment: great question @ZemmouriTarek; this is how [bash pipelines](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074072) work; the dash "-" simply says that there are no more options and should input the output from the first part

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the newline after the end of the file variable is present. If not, the following error would have appeared:

```
Load key "/home/.../....tmp/ID_RSA": invalid format
 [MASKED]@...: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The `ID_RSA` was my file variable in this example.

Answer (score 6):

I got it working with a protected variable.

If the variable is file, `echo` won't work anymore:

```
cat "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
```

Otherwise; if variable is NOT file, use the following:

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
```

Answer (score 5):

If you export key from **PuTTYgen**, to get key content use its command **Conversations** - **Export OpenSSH key (force new file format)**

And trim last spaces and add new line.

Answer (score 3):

It is the SSH public key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub by default.

The private key is contained in ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 2):

You must copy the entire contents of the file(id_rsa), including the final blank line. I solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after spending some hours trying to understand what was wrong I found that my private key was encrypted (and my computer had the password in cache for so long that I had forgotten that it was encrypted). It's not so easy to understand if it's encrypted or not by just looking at the key.
You should decrypt the key (set an empty password) and then paste it on a GitLab variable. Then in your .gitlab-ci.yml you can have a similar configuration:

```
before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo -e "Host *\nStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

*** Note that if you don't want to write the key in a file, you can just put it inside the ssh agent with:

```
- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
```

*** Note 2: In the Gitlab panel, make sure you have created a variable (and not a file); normally, it should be protected if you want to make it visible in the main branch.

*** Important: For security reasons change the following line:

```
- echo -e "Host *\nStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

putting only your host/s (and don't permit all connections like this).
If you put:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

when connecting to any host, the ssh-agent will not check the signature and this can be a big vulnerability!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on gitlab and bitbucket, both were solved adding a \n by the end of the key file.

```
echo $'' >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

## Keeping `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` protected

Making my tags `protected` fixed the issue for me. Here is how to do it: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_tags.html

Note the definition of `Protect variable`:

```
Export variable to pipelines running on protected branches and tags only.
```

Whether or not tags were created on commits on a protected branch did not matter apparently. GitLab has an independent notion of `protected tags` which disregards what branch the underlying commit is in.

Otherwise, if you are running the pipeline on `branch commits`, make sure that branch is a `protected` one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I had made my SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable available in a specific enviroment. I changed it to the one I was using (or you can change it to All, depending on your setup).

Answer (score 0):

it possible you didn't copy the content of the public key to the authorized_keys

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the stupid me was using inconsistent variable name.

I defined `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` in GitLab's variables and was using `OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

That's why I hate working straight after lunch..

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to put '\n' on every line break and storing the key as ONE LINE in my variables and then using '-e' switch in echo:

```
echo -e $SECRET_KEY > key.pem
```

This worked and it also helped me to add the identity to ssh-add directly like this:

```
echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be helpful**

- Setup the ssh private key from the pipeline:

```
    .setupssh: &setupssh
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
        - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

- When you create a new branch from the master branch, the pipeline fails with this error:

  ```
   Error loading key "(stdin)": error in libcrypto
  ```

This happened because your $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is protected.

**Solution :**

Go to : `Settings > CI/CD > Variables` and edit the $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY, Uncheck `Protect Variable` if is checked.

Answer (score 0):

- first be sure that your variable $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is not projected
- then encode your private key to base64 for keeping the good format
- final add this line.

  -echo "$DEV_NODE_ONE_SSH_KEY" | tr -d '' | base64 --decode | ssh-add -