# How to write output to a file in if else statement in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write output to a file, the correct output is printed in the successful file and the same is printed in the unsuccessful log.
In the unsuccessful log it should print only unsuccessful logs but it is printing successful logs also.

```
for TASKARN  in `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster APPS --desired-status RUNNING --region us-east-1 --service-name coreservice-service | jq .taskArns[] | sed 's/.$//; s/^.//' | cut -d":" -f 6 | cut -d"/" -f 3`
do
echo $TASKARN
cd /tmp/
val=`find core-$TASKARN.log -maxdepth 0 -daystart -mtime -1`
if [ $val == core-$TASKARN.log ]
then
echo " core-$TASKARN.log is present " >> /opt/successfull.log
else
echo " core-$TASKARN.log is not present " >> /opt/unsuccessfull.log
fi
done
```

In successful log

core-26f374a6a.log is present

In unsuccessful log

core-26f374a6a.log is not present

Comment: shellcheck your code, fix the issues and then post the updated version if you still have a problem. See https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Agree with Ed. Shellcheck produced 5 findings on your code. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It is a great help for sharing the shellcheck.net tool.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) suggestions, you might consider the below points too..

- Replace `TASKARN` with `taskarn`. Full-uppercase variables are reserved as environment variables. You may accidentally override an environment variable if you set a full uppercase variable.
- Consider removing `cd /tmp/`. Instead do :

  ```
  val=$(find /tmp/ "core-${taskarn}.log" -maxdepth 0 -daystart -mtime -1)
  # When you embed a variable inside string consider curly braces. See reference.
  ```

<sub>[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/1620779)</sub>

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks.