# Array not populating with correct data

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I'm populating an array in a loop:

```
for k in one two three; do
  array+=( "$k" )
done
echo $k[0]  # should print one, instead prints one[0]
echo $k[1]  # should print two, instead prints one[1]
```

Why does this print `one[0]` instead of `one`?

Comment: You can set your array using JSON_DATA[0]=… but to access it you require ${JSON_DATA[0]} rather than $JSON_DATA[0] etc.

Comment: Hi borrible, thank you! please post this in an answer and I will accept this. This worked for me.

Comment: See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is edited into the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta]. You're welcome to use the "Add an Answer" button to add an answer separately, even to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your syntax when accessing arrays.  You can set them using `array[0]=` but to access them you require `${array[0]}` rather than `$array[0]` etc.

Comment: If you truly believe that this is a full answer to the question the OP asked, you should be voting to close the question as a duplicate of [When do we need brackets around shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831), per the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).