# Editing multiple files with bash

Tags: bash, text, sed, edit

So I have a bunch of files that I want to edit at once using `sed` but the problem is that I need to edit a line and change the text to a file name stored in variable filename. Every time I tried, it changes the text to the literal "filename" and I don't know how to fix it.

The command I've used is:

```
sed -i 's/$x/'$filename'/g' *.html
```

Comment: A good idea would be to show how you did it so we can understand it better and help you. Its hard to theoritically solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

From your description and the command used I assume that you try to replace a variable text stored in

```
X="text2replace"
```

with a filename stored in

```
FILENAME="filename"
```

According this, a command like

```
sed -i "s/${X}/${FILENAME}/g" *.html
```

should do the job. It will replace all occurrences of `text2replace` in all HTML files found with the string `filename`.

You may have also a look into

- [When do we need curly braces around shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and sed):

```
parallel --header : sed -i 's#{x}#{filename}#' {file} ::: file *.html ::: x pattern ::: filename name
```