# Accessing parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How do I access this variable in a shell script.

[image]

I have tried

1. `echo params.$STATES;`
2. `echo $STATES;`

Output for the first one is `params.` . Output for the second one is an empty string. The output I am expecting is the string I am passing when I build that job with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the 'Execute Shell' block in a Freestyle Project, you will need a `$` (dollar sign) before the variable. Since you already tried this, there could be an issue not wrapping variable within `{}`

- try `echo ${STATES}`
- More info on curly braces around variables,
  See: [codeforester answer on usage of curly braces around shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287079/10697591)

2. If you are using a Jenkinsfile without a shell block (valid in Scripted and Declarative)

- Use dollar sign with double quotes

```
node(){
    echo "$STATES"
}
```

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo "$STATES"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- or without Double quotes and dollar sign

```
node(){
    echo STATES
}
```

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo STATES
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. If you are using a Shell block in the Jenkinsfile pipeline, use
   `sh "echo $STATES"` or `sh "echo ${STATES}"`
   (as in the Freestyle Execute Shell block, Double quotes are needed for interpolation)

See

- [String interpolation in Jenkinsfiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation)
- [Handling parameters in Jenkinsfiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-parameters)

Comment: None of these worked for me in my freestyle project