# Operators and user input not found / unexpected while checking if users and groups exist in /etc/group and /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, grep, user-input

I can't understand what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to make it so that if the passed in username and group are both not found in /etc/group and etc/passwd echo both not found.

If one but not the other is found echo one is found and finally if they are both found then echo both exist.

Here is my code:

```
#/bin/bash

read -p 'Username: ' username
read -p 'Group: ' group

if [ $(grep "^$group:" /etc/group | cut -f 1 -d ':') != $group ] && [ $(grep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d ':') != $username ]
then 
  echo Both not found 

elif $(grep "^$group:" /etc/group | cut -f 1 -d ':') != $group ] || [ $(grep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d ':') != $username ]
then
  echo One exists, one does not.

elif $(grep "^$group:" /etc/group | cut -f 1 -d ':') = $group ] && [ $(grep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d ':') = $username ]
then
  echo both exist
fi
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./exercise_10.sh        
Username: user
Group: root
./exercise_10.sh: 10: root: not found
./exercise_10.sh: 14: root: not found
                                                                                                                                                                               
$ ./exercise_10.sh
Username: dfgdfggd
Group: root
./exercise_10.sh: 10: root: not found
./exercise_10.sh: 10: [: !=: unexpected operator
./exercise_10.sh: 14: root: not found
                                                                                                                                                                               
$ ./exercise_10.sh
Username: dfgdg
Group: cgdgdfg
./exercise_10.sh: 6: [: !=: unexpected operator
./exercise_10.sh: 10: !=: not found
./exercise_10.sh: 10: [: !=: unexpected operator
./exercise_10.sh: 14: =: not found
```

I've tested the grep and cut command in the command line and it works:

```
$ grep '^user:' /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d ':'
user
```

Comment: As the [bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) you used in your question instructs you to do - copy/paste your shell script(s) into https://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that tool tells you about before posting here if you still have a problem afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing `!` in the shebang, the first line should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

There are missing `[` right after the `elif`s.

You could always use `shellcheck` command to parse and list all issues in a bash script:

```
shellcheck ./exercise_10.sh
```

Finally you could rely on `grep` command return status with `if` statements like the one below:

```
if grep -q "^${group}:" /etc/group 2>/dev/null && grep -q "^${username}:" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null ; then
  printf "Both exist.\n"
...
```

Give a try to this, which only parse each file once:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp 'Username: ' lusername
read -rp 'Group: ' lgroup

if grep -q "^${lgroup}:" /etc/group 2>/dev/null ; then
  if grep -q "^${lusername}:" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null ; then
    printf "Both exist\n"
  else 
    printf "One exists, one does not\n"
  fi
else
  if grep -q "^${lusername}:" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null ; then
    printf "One exists, one does not\n"
  else
    printf "Both not found\n"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that does work nicely, however I'm not quite sure what the 2 into dev/null is for?

Comment: Oh also just noticed you have curly braces around the user inputs when they're begin grepped. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-around-shell-variables but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `2>/dev/null` redirects output from the preceding command to stderr instead of stdout. The curly braces are doing nothing useful in this script, they don't hurt but you could leave them out.

Comment: It's a reflex: I always use curly braces because it eases the reading having one only way to handle variables in lines of code.