# "no such file or directory:" using function though they exist

Tags: bash, function, alias

in my `~/.bash_aliases` i have a function:

```
function fresh() {

  if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    # If no params added, source both bash_aliases and aliases.zsh
    "cp $HOME/.bash_aliases $ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh; source $HOME/.bash_aliases $ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh; echo 'Aliases Refreshed (Bash + Zsh).'"
    return 0
  fi

  CMD=$1
  shift

  case $CMD in
    b|bash)
      # Source bash_aliases (only)
      "source $HOME/.bash_aliases; echo 'Aliases Refreshed (Bash).'"
      ;;
    z|zsh|zash)
      # Source aliases.zsh (only)
      "source $ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh; echo 'Aliases Refreshed (Zsh).'"
      ;;
  esac
  return $?
}
```

The default `fresh` w/no args makes a copy of `~/.bash_aliases` and just renames it to `aliases.zsh`, and then sources both files.

It worked fine as an actual alias, but moving it to a function I now get this:

```
fresh:4: no such file or directory: cp /home/scott/.bash_aliases /home/scott/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh; source /home/scott/.bash_aliases /home/scott/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh; echo 'Aliases Refreshed (Bash + Zsh).'
```

If I literally copy and paste each command from it, they work:

[image]

and changes confirmed by doing a `cat $ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh` and looking for the changes.

Any idea why it's complain that one of the files or dirs isn't found? Do I need to `cd` to some dir first? (seems like I shouldn't have to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command like `"cp here there"` will attempt to locate and run an executable file called, `cp here there` (the full command), it will *not* try to run `cp` with the `here` and `there` as arguments.

For example, the first `ls` command below works, the second does not (because it's not *actually* an `ls` command):

```bash
pax@styx> ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 21 root root 4096 Mar 20 07:27 /tmp

pax@styx> "ls -ld /tmp"
-bash: ls -ld /tmp: No such file or directory
```

If you had "literally cop[ied] and paste[d] each command" *including* the quotes, you would have seen the same problem.

The solution, therefore, is to *remove* the `"` characters from the command, as well as the other similar commands within your `case` statement.

Just remember to quote the actual *arguments* (I always surround variables with `{}` as well) if there's a chance they could contain white space, such as with:

```bash
cp "${HOME}/.bash_aliases" "${ZSH_CUSTOM}/aliases.zsh"
```

Comment: I managed to solve my own problem just after posting. Still learning the ins and outs of bash quoting. This ended up working `cp "$HOME/.bash_aliases" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh"; source "$HOME/.bash_aliases" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/aliases.zsh"; echo 'Aliases Refreshed (Bash + Zsh).'`

Comment: What's the benefit of always wrapping vars in braces?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Braces around a variable reference are sometimes needed to disambiguate where the variable reference ends. For example, should `$variable` mean `${variable}`, `${v}ariable`, or `${var}iable`, etc? Similarly, should `$var/foo/bar` mean `${var}/foo/bar` or `${var/foo/bar}`? Even when they're not needed, braces can still be used for consistency and/or clarity. See ["When do we need curly braces around shell variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/when-do-we-need-curly-braces-around-shell-variables)