# How to copy recursive directories to a flat directory

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to copy all the *.psd files, currently in a multi directories structure, into one single directory.
Is there an rsync parametrization to allow it?

The solution proposed at [Copying files from multiple directories into a single destination directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460177/copying-files-from-multiple-directories-into-a-single-destination-directory) is not a multilevel recursive directories, only single level subdirectories.

In my current case I have files in multiple recursive directories (up to 7 levels) that I would like to reconcile in a single directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from multiple directories into a single destination directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460177/copying-files-from-multiple-directories-into-a-single-destination-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fear `rsync` can't help you here. You can use `find` to find all the files and copy them to the destination directory, though:

```
find /path/to/source/topdir -type f -name '*.psd' -exec cp {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion @choroba's answer is the right one.

For completeness (or if for any reason you needed the files to be copied with rsync) you can do something way less efficient using `rsync` (which is just like using `cp` in this case), using find, a loop and other things not really necessary.

```
for file in $(find ./path/to/source/topdir -name "*psd" ); do rsync $file /path/to/destination/; done
```