# Run npm install recursively if package.json is present

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, bash, ubuntu, angular6

I have a root directory with a lot of child directories. 
I want to run `npm install` in each directory if a file with name package.json is present in that directory. I have to still consider some scenarios as below

## After running npm install, it will create a new directory node_modules. If I re-run the command it should not check package.json present inside a directory with name node_modules.

I have tried

```
find . -name "package.json" -exec npm i \;
```

Comment: I think you're pretty close to the solution. npm i needs a foldername and with ``-exec npm i {} \;``   -- {} is the found file, but you need the folder of the file. I'm no bash expert, but something like this may work  ``-exec npm i dirname {} \;`` via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121091/get-file-directory-path-from-file-path

Comment: Thanks, @GordonMohrin. It works for now. But the next major step is, I should be able to rerun the command. When I re-run It should go into a particular folder with name node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was (using Yarn package manager):

`find . -type f -name package.json -exec bash -c 'yarn install --cwd $(dirname {})' \;`

This command finds all `package.json` files recursively from current working directory. Then it executes a command (e.g. `yarn install --cwd`) with the pathname of the found `package.json` file.

You can use this command with `npm install` as well:

`find . -type f -name package.json -exec bash -c 'npm install $(dirname {})' \;`

You can optionally add `-maxdepth N` to the find command to limit the depth of the recursive find. This is to prevent a long running command because packages in `node_modules` folders have their own `package.json` files.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude node_modules directory

```
find . -type f -name package.json -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname {}) && npm install && npm audit fix' \;
```